# How to Install j2me polish with Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, java-me, j2mepolish

How can I integrate J2ME Polish with Eclipse?

I tried many ways but did not get any success.

Answer (score 3):

Well, I was a big fan of eclipse IDE but I must say that for developing on J2ME, Netbeans provides a much friendlier environment. I have used j2me polish quite extensively, including developing custom components, submitting new code/patches , commercial deployment. I would strongly recommend Netbeans IDE; if you are willing to try, I have provided elaborate steps to use J2ME polish on Netbeans here:

[J2me -Polish ---Problem related to create and build the project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4256224/j2me-polish-problem-related-to-create-and-build-the-project/4257605#4257605)

Do let me know if you have any trouble setting it up.

Answer (score 0):

This should help

https://harshitdubey99.wordpress.com/2010/07/11/j2me-polish/