# J2me -Polish ---Problem related to create and build the project

Tags: java-me, j2mepolish

I am beginner of j2me-polish.I had installed j2me-polish2.1.4.As per the steps shown in below link:-
http://www.j2mepolish.org/cms/leftsection/documentation/installation/ide-integration/netbeans/installation.html

After installing it,I tried to create project by following the step in below link:-
http://www.j2mepolish.org/cms/leftsection/documentation/installation/ide-integration/netbeans/creating-projects.html

But i am unable to create the project.it is showing me reference problem.And wen i tried to solve that problem my adding the emulator of nokia N97 then it not happening properly.

I can't able to build the program.Please help me out.

Please can u help me the for the proper steps related to creating the project and selection the option.
Thanxs a lot in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I follow the following steps and it works for me all the time. Download J2ME-Polish2.1.4, install the library and also Netbeans plugin. Perhaps you will need to restart the IDE. Now,

1. Create a project (for example Polish Table) in Netbeans, making use of J2ME polish plugin. Let's call it
2. Copy all files except nbproject directory in /samples/tableitem/ to NetBeans  directory. Override build.xml created  by Netbeans during this copying process.
3. Copy contents of /samples/tableitem/nbproject (except private folder) to  directory. Override all the files.
4. Switch to  NetBeans  directory
5. Edit project.xml file. Comment out  tag. Rename project name in  tag to the project name created in Netbeans (i.e. Polish Table )
6. Edit project.properties file in nbproject directory. Change src.dir from src to source/src
7. Edit project.properties file in nbproject directory. Make sure that libs.classpath= property points to J2ME polish import client library. If not found, make sure that the following two lines are added:
8. file.reference.enough-j2mepolish-client.jar=C:/J2ME-Polish/import/enough-j2mepolish-client.jar
   9.libs.classpath=${file.reference.enough-j2mepolish-client.jar}

Restart NetBeans IDE. From now on you can work completely using IDE. However you will need to compile from command line. Even this could be integrated - but didn't bother to figure out.
Hopefully this should be sufficient to get you started.

Comment: Thanks for the answer,but can you please tell me that from where and how to install library and netbeans plugin for polish.And how can i create the a project in netbeans,amking use of of j2me polish plugin. I know this might be basic but i am completely new to polish and netbeans too.So please help me .

Comment: Shweta, You can download Netbeans IDE at the following location:http://netbeans.org/downloads/start.html?platform=windows&lang=en&option=java. First install Netbeans IDE and then install J2ME Polish. The later can be downloaded from their web site at http://www.j2mepolish.org/cms/leftsection/download.html. Plugin for Netbeans is available in the polish library installer. You only have to point to polish installer the location of Netbeans.